# Defining Rules for Bit Vectors in SMT2

Tags: z3, smt, quantifiers, bitvector, first-order-logic

I have switched from using Int to Bit Vectors in SMT. However, the logic QF_BV does not allow the use of any quantifiers in your script, and I need to define FOL rules.
I know how to eliminate existential quantifiers, but universal quantifiers? How to do that?

Imagine a code like that:

```
(set-logic QF_AUFBV)

(define-sort Index () (_ BitVec 3))

(declare-fun P (Index) Bool)

(assert (forall ((i Index)) (= (P (bvadd i #b001)) (not (P i)) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you're out-of-luck. According to http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/logics.shtml, there's no logic that contains quantifiers and bit-vectors at the same time.

Having said that, most solvers will allow non-standard combinations. Simply leave out the `set-logic` command, and you might get lucky. For instance, Z3 takes your query just fine without the `set-logic` part; I just tried..

Comment: Indeed, Z3 also recognizes the UFBV and BV logics (without QF_). There are also some benchmarks in SMTLIB for those, so I expect they'll soon become official logics.

Comment: The new SMT-LIB 2.5 standard defines `(set-logic ALL)` for choosing the  most  general  logic the solver supports. (SMT-LIB 2.5 was released on June 28, 2015.)